# Statistics Badge Typo

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, user-interface

Just a small typo I noticed, it appears that the mouseover text for the bronze-statistics badge says:

> bronze badge: **1000** upvotes on 20 questions.

Comment: It's a statistical anomaly. :-)

Comment: It's certainly not statistically significant :)

Comment: Thanks for posting that, Robert.  I had noticed that myself - given that it was me that it was awarded to. :)  And the other error associated with the badge is that it doesn't seem to be counted among my total number of bronze badges.

Answer (score 6):

Yep, this is already fixed pending deploy. Sorry about that.

Comment: The problem pointed out by Robert Wiberg has been fixed, but the other one (in my comment above) has not.  My user page lists 67 badges - 51 bronze - but my little profile that appears when I make a post says I have 66 - 50 bronze.  It's not a big deal, but it does appear to be a bug related to the statistics badge.

Comment: I manually synced your badge count -- better?

Comment: Thanks, Jeff...